# Prime divisors of the integer $n^2+n-1$ (using the Legendre symbol)

Tags: modular-arithmetic

What made me have a question is the following problem.

> The prime divisors $p\not=5$ of the integer $n^2+n-1$ are of the form
>   $10k+1$ or $10k+9$.

I thought $\left(\frac 5 p\right) = 1$, because $5 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

So $\left(\frac 5 p\right) = (-1)^{p-1}\left(\frac p 5\right)=1$ by qudratic reciprocity.

Then $p$ should be of the form $2k+1$

But I think there is something wrong, and I have lost.

Is there someone to help me?

Comment: If $p$ divides $n^2+n-1$, it also divides $4(n^2+n-1)$. Try to see how that relates to $5$.

Comment: Do you mean $(2n+1)^2\equiv 5\pmod p$?  If yes, I knew already. But I can't go further.

Comment: Okay, so you know $\left(\frac5p\right) = 1$. Have you heard of quadratic reciprocity?

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned above, I tried to use $\left( \frac 5 p\right)$. I edited my post because of typing error.

Comment: "Then $p$ should be of the form $2k+1$." Well, yes, but every prime (except $p=2$) is of the form $2k+1$. And quadratic reciprocity says $(5\mid p)=(p\mid5)$.

Comment: Thank you, I find the place where I think wrongly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n^2+n-1$ is odd, so all its prime factors are odd. You have found that if $p\mid n^2+n-1$, then $(2n+1)^2 \equiv 5 \pmod{p}$, and so for $p\neq 5$ you have $\left(\frac5p\right) = 1$. Quadratic reciprocity then yields $\left(\frac{p}{5}\right) = 1$, since $5 \equiv 1\pmod{4}$. So $p$ is a quadratic residue modulo $5$, and that means $p \equiv\: ? \pmod{5}$?

Comment: Thanks to your answer (especially last sentence), I understand it. Thank you.